# How to store/cache request data from CMS in Vue3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, laravel-nova

I've built a primitive `Content Management System` with `Laravel Nova` in a `Vue3/Laravel8 app`. Being the noob I am, I am using `axios.get` to get image links and markdown from a `database` and assign it to a `reactive state` like so:

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
import marked from "marked";

const state = reactive({
    locale: sessionStorage.locale,
    content: "",
    image: ""
})

axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data[0]
        state.content = DOMPurify.sanitize(marked(data['content_' + state.locale]))
        state.image = 'storage/' + data['image']
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.response);
    });

</script>
```

and render the `image/markdown` in my template:

```
<template>
  <section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="home-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + state.image + ')'}"></div>
    <div v-html="state.content"></div>
  </section>
</template>
```

This creates 2 problems:

1. The app has to wait for the `response` every time the page is refreshed or loaded.
2. The `images/content` are rendered every time the page is refreshed or loaded.

Is there a way to cache the `response data`? I just need to store the `string information`.

I've tried doing that with `sessionStorage` but it doesn't work with `state = reactive()` during the initial page load (or is there a way?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to achieve this. You just need to convert the object to a string when setting and convert back when using it.

Example:

```js
...
  const setState = data => {
    state.content = DOMPurify.sanitize(marked(data['content_' + state.locale]))
    state.image = 'storage/' + data['image']
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('home')) {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('home'))
    setState(data[0])
  } else {
    axios.get('/home')
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('home', JSON.stringify(res.data))
        setState(res.data[0])
      })
  }
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bhz8jpa/)

Comment: But this wouldn't be `reactive` would it? `ss/ls` are not reactive.

Comment: It's not related. The localStorage only store string when we get it and set it back to reactive object it still be reactive except you do something like: `state = ...`. You can see from the fiddle if is not reactive it will not change the content.